# Interest Rate Swap Question

Tags: interest-rate-swap

I am new to IRS. Pay 2Y HKD-USD IRS spread. It is a trade idea recommendation. Can someone explain what this trade entails? Does it mean paying fixed and receiving 3m USD LIBOR over 2 years? Please advise.

Thanks.

Zach